# Pass target item ID to ajax callback on Application Express (Apex) dynamic form

Tags: ajax, oracle-apex

Extending nice work by Trent Schafer ( https://apextips.blogspot.ca/2015/05/building-dynamic-forms.html),

I've added a select list containing record title/summary next to each answer item, leveraging Oracle Text, based on the static question.

The aforementioned link is used to populate the page structure (seen below with mods) plus the save action (not shown below). The `onchange` event of the select list will retrieve the full record and populate the answer item, identifying it by its ID, created in the anonymous block and named `ans_var2`.

The `onchange` event is causing a `TypeError` in the variables declaration section specific to the variable, `ans_var2`.

`ans_var2` is supposed to be passed in via `p_attributes`.

The console is returning 'undefined'.

I've tested the code below using a defined answer item ID with success, but the form is dynamic with an unknown number of Q/A pairs.

**Question**

Please advise if there's a functional way to send in the dynamically generated answer item ID, as the `ans_var2` method may simply be wrong, or with incorrect syntax.

Apex 5.1.2

```
--***Function and Global Variable Declaration***

function myFunction(val, ans_var2) {

apex.server.process(
    'lab_ondemand',                             // Process or AJAX Callback name
    {x01: val
    },  // Parameter "x01"
     {
      success: function (pData) {             // Success Javascript
    apex.item("ans_var2").setValue(pData);
      },
      dataType: "text"                        // Response type (here: plain text)
    }
  );
}

--***PL/SQL Dynamic Content***

declare
ans_length number;
id_holder varchar2(4000) :='';
ans_var2 varchar2(4000) :='';
begin

    for i in (
        select *
        from v_dynamic_qs
    )
    loop    

sys.htp.prn('<table border="1" style="wide: 100%">');
sys.htp.prn('<tbody>');
sys.htp.prn('<tr>');     

    sys.htp.prn(' <td style="width:400px; valign:top";>');
    sys.htp.prn('ID: ' || i.ID || '<br> Question Key: '||  i.question_key || '<br> Answer ID: ' || i.ans_id || '<br>');
    sys.htp.prn(i.ID || '. ' || i.question_key || ' ' || i.ans_id);
sys.htp.prn('<a title="Properties" href="'||apex_util.prepare_url('f?p='||:APP_ID||':10:&SESSION.:::10:P10_ID:'||i.ID)||' "> <img src="#APP_IMAGES#go_icon.png" title="" alt="Open MS Word" height="22" width="22"></a>');
sys.htp.prn('<a title="" href="'||apex_util.prepare_url('f?p='||:APP_ID||':12000:&SESSION.:::10:P12000_ID,P12000_ANS_ID:'||i.ID || ',' || i.ANS_ID)||' "> <img src="#APP_IMAGES#find.jpg" title="" alt="" height="22" width="22"></a>');

sys.htp.prn(' </td>');
sys.htp.prn(' <td style="width:400px; valign:top";>');

if i.question_type = 'TEXT'
        then
            htp.prn('<p> <input class="dynamicQs" id="QS_' || i.question_key || '" type="text" value="' || i.question_ans || '" /></p>');
        elsif i.question_type = 'TEXTAREA'
        then
            htp.prn('<p> <textarea class="dynamicQs" id="QS_' || i.question_key || '">' || i.question_ans || '</textarea></p>');

select 'QS_' || i.question_key into ans_var2 from dual;           

end if;    

id_holder := i.ans_id;
            htp.p(
                APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY_XL(
    p_idx           =>    1,
    p_value         =>    NULL,
    p_query         =>    'select QUESTION from TBLRECORDS where contains(myindex, ''about(' ||i.question_key||')'', 1) >0',
    p_attributes    =>    'style="width:250px;" onchange="myFunction(this.value, ans_var2);"',             
    p_show_null     =>    'YES',
    p_null_value    =>    '%NULL%',
    p_null_text     =>    '',
    p_item_id       =>    id_holder,
    p_item_label    =>    NULL,
    p_show_extra    =>    'YES')
            );

    sys.htp.prn(' </td>');                               
    htp.p('<br /><br />');     
  sys.htp.prn('</tr>');
  end loop;
sys.htp.prn('</tbody>');    
sys.htp.prn('</table>');
end;

--***Ajax Callback***

declare
  l_emprow TBLRECORDS%ROWTYPE;
begin
  select * into l_emprow
  from TBLRECORDS 
  where QUESTION = apex_application.g_x01;
  htp.p(
        'ANSWER:'||l_emprow.ANSWER);
end;
```

Comment: Please advise if anyone can assist. I'm getting a type error when trying to pass the target field through to the on demand process by the on change call. The obstacle is large for me as I'm new to on demand processes and would appreciate any points of wisdom. Thanks.